# Cardano-Vieta applied to $\cos(5\alpha) = 16\cos^5(\alpha) - 20\cos^3(\alpha) + 5 \cos(\alpha)$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, complex-numbers

I'm given this equality:

$\cos(5\alpha) = 16\cos^5(\alpha) - 20\cos^3(\alpha) + 5 \cos(\alpha)$

Form there, we make the substitution $x = \cos(\alpha)$ and $p = \cos(5\alpha)$ and we obtain the equation:

$16x^5 - 20x^3 + 5x - p = 0$ and it says the 5 roots of these polynomial are:

$\cos(\alpha),\ \cos(\alpha+72),\ \cos(\alpha+144),\ \cos(\alpha+216),\ \cos(\alpha + 288)$. Why does the polynomial have these roots?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because this equality is valid for *every* value of $\alpha$?

Comment: What do you mean "it says the roots are..."  What's "it" here?  Are you reading something in a book, from lecture notes, a website?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\cos(5\alpha) = Re\left[e^{5i\alpha}\right] = Re\left[\left(e^{i \alpha}\right)^5\right]$$

and use [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) to find the fifth roots of $(e^{i \alpha})^5$ and then take the real part to get the roots you have listed.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the problem around the other way.
We are looking for solutions to $16x^5-20x^3+5x-p=0$, where $p$ is some given constant.

Introduce the change of variables $x=\cos\alpha$.
Now the equation reads
$$16\cos^5\alpha-20\cos^3\alpha+5\cos\alpha=p$$
Using the identity $\cos 5\alpha = 16\cos^5\alpha - 20\cos^3\alpha+5\cos\alpha$, this becomes
$$\cos 5\alpha=p$$
Provided that $p$ is between $1$ and $-1$, this can be solved as follows:
$$5\alpha = \cos^{-1}p$$
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{5}\cos^{-1}p$$
So compute $\alpha$ from that formula, and back-substitute it into $x=\cos\alpha$ to get a solution to the original equation.

However, keep in mind that $5\alpha = \cos^{-1}p$ is just *one* possible solution to the equation $\cos 5\alpha=p$.  You can get more solutions by adding multiples of $360°$.  That is, we could have any of the following:
$$5\alpha = \cos^{-1}p$$
$$5\alpha=\cos^{-1}p+360$$
$$5\alpha=\cos^{-1}p+720$$
$$5\alpha=\cos^{-1}p+1080$$
$$5\alpha=\cos^{-1}p+1440$$

Dividing these each by 5 gives you the five solutions you have in your question.

Comment: Great explanation.  Question: Unless I wrote the problem, what would make me suspect that $16x^5−20x^3+5x$ is the expansion of $\cos$? That is, is there something that suggests this approach, or is must it be supplied by the problem's author (who must have worked backwards to create the question)?